# update column only if there is value in laravel request

Tags: php, laravel

6 project 
everything working good 
but i have problem with custom requests 
this is my request code on create data

```
'password' => 'required|min:3',
```

this is my request code on update data

```
'password' => 'nullable|min:3',
```

now my problem every time i update users if i didn't put any value on password filed the user password gonna be null but i need the request change it only if there is data in the request thanks a lot

Comment: did you use `when` method?

Comment: Or just check `if (!empty($request->password)) 
then update data`

Comment: could you writ the code please

Comment: i cant do that because i use update like this     $user->update($request->all());

Comment: @AwarPulldozer This is not the type of response we want from our users. We want to encourage and help you. Ever hear the phrase: "You give a poor man a fish and you feed him for a day. You teach him to fish and you give him an occupation that will feed him for a lifetime."? It applies to programming as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [filled](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-filled) validation rule:

```
// update request rules
'password' => 'filled|min:3',
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if not empty

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
     // your validation
     if (!empty($request->password)) {
           // update user password
     }
     // write some response
}
```